# Having an issue with a SQL string not actually doing anything

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I'm working on a project for college (UK College, not University) and it's pretty small but incorporates some SQL because I have a database for keeping track of everything the user does. On my account creation page I have a query that runs this SQL against my database:

```
INSERT INTO Users (UName, FName, SName, PWord, ULevel)
VALUES (:pmUName, :pmFName, :pmSName, :pmPWord, :pmULevel);
```

Anything that starts with `:pm` is a parameter that I can control in Delphi, I'm just wondering if there's something massively crucial I'm missing as it doesn't insert into the table `Users` when executed.

Comment: what do the logs say ? (they still teach delphi, wow)

Comment: Might be everything, without table schema and error logs it’s impossible to answer. However, it is _very_ strange that you `INSERT` a _new record_ with only a `ULevel` and no other data. A wild guess of mine is that you have omitted non-nullable columns without default from your insertions...

Comment: I don't have any logs, I'm not sure how I'd generate one either, but it seems that it isn't even touching the database, I'm running an Access 2003 database because that seems to be the only thing Delphi will communicate with on this type of connection (I think it's an older protocol, I used it in XE4 but it's what I'm used to now in XE10). Adding the things that StevenMcGovern suggested, the layout of the table looks like [this](http://imgur.com/a/eFtVT), and I've since moved the ULevel to look like the edited original post

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Are you properly committing the insert? Are you properly handling errors in your code?

Comment: Can you post the Delphi code that you use to execute that SQL ?, it must be something lacking there.

Comment: Which Delphi dataset component are you using to execute the INSERT statement?  And please do what @MarcGuillot asks.

Comment: I'm new to this and trying to figure out most of it on my own so you might consider the code sloppy, but the procedure code for setting parameters and executing the SQL is [this](http://imgur.com/a/LJipX), I've used Imgur because of the character limit, and I'm using the 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider on a TADOconnection with a TADOquery, I know the connection string is correct because the same string will extract information from the database, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that it won't write. If you need any more information ask away.

Comment: There's no character limit involved with the small snippet you posted. Code in images is useless here. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you are using you may be running your SQL in a transaction that need to be committed? (i.e. `BEGIN;` normally starts a transaction and `COMMIT` will commit everything or `ROLLBACK` if there was some error in any of the SQL).

But as a first step your logs will reveal the actual error as suggested by NimChimpsky.

Answer (score 0):

This might get my question downvoted, but after tracing through the code a million times I noticed the validation of my username was reversed, so if the username already existed it would pass through but if it didn't it would return false and not execute the SQL. I wrote that particular code a long time ago and didn't think it would be the issue until I had a friend look over the project and they decided to trace through it. There was nothing actually wrong with the SQL, so many apologies to people who dedicated their time to diagnosing a non-issue.

TLDR:
Make sure code is executing before you assume the code is wrong

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, it just goes to prove that two pairs of eyes are better then one.   Another thing to do is try explaining to someone what your code is doing.  But, this shouldn't really be in an answer here, so please replace it by an edit to your q (though you may find it's then voted off-topic).

Comment: I've heard of something called the rubber duck solution, where programmers explain their solution to a rubber duck and that helps them debug an issue. I may have to go buy a duck......